# Help with bolding numbers with XeLaTeX

Tags: vector, scientific-notation

I am using:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
```

to help typeset mathematical notation with XeLaTeX. I used the following to change typesetting vectors with an arrow above to bold face:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\symbfit{#1}}}
```

However, if I have an arrow above a number, that number will not get bolded. Instead, the arrow above the number will just disappear and only the number itself remains. How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you want the arrow to be bold as well? Or just the number?

Comment: Just the number. The goal is to change all arrows to italic bold to indicate vectors.

Comment: I don't think Latin Modern Math has bold+italic for numbers, note that `\symbf{\vec{3}}` works (bold only) but `\symbfit{\vec{3}}` does not work (the number is upright and not bold). You could try another font.

Comment: Actually I wouldn't mind if the numbers are not italic bold. However, I wish to italic bold alphabets. Is there a way to redefine commands such that the alphabets are italic bold while the numbers are bold upright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a command that tests if the argument is an integer. If this is the case then you can print a bold symbol (using `\symbf`) with a vector arrow, and if it is false then you can print a bold+italic symbol (using `\symbfit`) with a vector arrow. The integer test `\IfInteger` is provided by the `xstring` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xstring}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\newcommand{\vecbfit}[1]{%
\IfInteger{#1}{%
\symbf{\vec{#1}}}{% true
\symbfit{\vec{#1}}}% false
}
\begin{document}
$\vecbfit{3} \vecbfit{A}$
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]